# Where do I download the Ubuntu touch Rom?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I have the nexus 4 where do I download the ubuntu touch rom because I cant find it on your site anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You should be following [the Touch/Install](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install) instructions.

The general procedure is as follows:

1. Desktop Setup (Setup the Touch Developer Preview Tools)
2. Back up Android Device.
3. Unlock device.
4. Download and deploy factory image.

The factory images for the Nexus Devices are [here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occam).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the image you're looking for:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/current/